# BaseHTTPServer POST request - Connection Reset

Tags: python, http, basehttpserver, basehttprequesthandler

I am building a simple Python tool that takes GPS coordinates from an external receiver via COM port and translates it to a JSON string like is returned by Google Geolocation API. The purpose is to replace the Google Geolocation provider URL in Firefox with a local one that serves this string back to the browser, thus implementing GPS-based location in my browser.

The GPS part is fine, but I am having trouble with the HTTP server to send the data to the browser. When the browser requests location from Google, it sends a POST like this:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=KEY HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

{}
```

This is my code to respond to it:

```py
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer

PORT_NUMBER = 8080

class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','application/json; charset=UTF-8')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('{"location": {"lat": 33.333333, "lng": -33.333333}, "accuracy": 5}')
        return

try:
    server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
    print 'Started httpserver on port ', PORT_NUMBER
    server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'Shutting down server'
    server.socket.close()
```

So it works fine when I send a POST request from Curl that's empty, but not when the request is the one sent by the browser (i. e. '{}' in the body):

```
curl --data "{}" http://localhost:8080
> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset

curl --data "foo" http://localhost:8080
> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset

curl --data "" http://localhost:8080
> {"location": {"lat": 33.333333, "lng": -33.333333}, "accuracy": 5}
```

I'm not familiar with HTTP protocol or BaseHTTPServer at all. Why is this going wrong? How can I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The best I have been able to come up with is that I needed to do something with the posted content, so I just added these two lines to the beginning of the `do_POST` handler:

```
    content_len = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length', 0))
    post_body = self.rfile.read(content_len)
```